# Resolving error 'java.lang.NumberFormatException' in SQL query

Tags: sql, jsp

I need help on my SQL query and JSP form code. I need to search for the `empid` or the `firstname` or the `lastname` of employee table but I'm getting an error.

**Code:**

```
String val = request.getParameter("srchBox");
            String fnval = request.getParameter(val).toString();
            String lnval = request.getParameter(val).toString();
            int idval = Integer.parseInt(val);
            try {
                con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                 out.println("error " + ex);
            }
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID="+idval+" OR FIRST_NAME="+fnval+" OR LAST_NAME="+lnval+"";
```

**Error:**

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Liza"

Comment: Post your code, sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the SQL syntax, here is the approach

```
    SELECT * FROM employee 
    WHERE empid = SomeIntegerValue 
       OR firstname = 'SomeStringValue' 
       OR lastname = 'SomeStringValue'
```

My answer is base on the information you provided above, if you can post what you have tried so far, or your query and desired out, we can further help you on your problem.